# Tensorflow NAN loss result for RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using an Anaconda environment within Windows 10. I'm using python 3.6.13, numpy 1.19.5, and tensorflow 2.1.0

I'm attempting to create an RNN for time series prediction, but I keep getting nan as a loss value. I'm using the following function as the loss function:

```
warmup_steps = 50
def loss_mse_warmup(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    Calculate the Mean Squared Error between y_true and y_pred,
    but ignore the beginning "warmup" part of the sequences.
    
    y_true is the desired output.
    y_pred is the model's output.
    """

    # The shape of both input tensors are:
    # [batch_size, sequence_length, num_y_signals].

    # Ignore the "warmup" parts of the sequences
    # by taking slices of the tensors.
    y_true_slice = y_true[:, warmup_steps:, :]
    y_pred_slice = y_pred[:, warmup_steps:, :]

    # These sliced tensors both have this shape:
    # [batch_size, sequence_length - warmup_steps, num_y_signals]

    # Calculat the Mean Squared Error and use it as loss.
    mse = mean(square(y_true_slice - y_pred_slice))
    
    return mse
```

In addition, when formatting the data, I removed all columns with NANs with `df.dropna()`

Here's my model

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(GRU(units=128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, num_x_signals)))

model.add(Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid')) 

optimizer = Adam(clipvalue=1)

model.compile(loss=loss_mse_warmup, optimizer=optimizer)
```

My model only returns nan as a loss result, does anyone know why this is happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: What is the x and y shape?

Comment: @Kaveh `x_shape = (256, 1050, 9)`, `y_shape = (256, 1050, 1)`, I'll also edit my post to include my batch generator function.

Comment: The code looks fine for this shape. However it could be say more certainly if you say, what is the value of `num_x_signals` and `num_y_signals`? And what type of values stored in `y`? 0 and 1? integer numbers? float values?

Comment: I ran the above code in TF 2.6 with no error. providing gist for reference .  https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/bc8fb5aa96d5108294507ee9e930e615/stack_68591775.ipynb